# How to Get Mute Button to appear on-top of a full screen 360 video using a frame

Tags: javascript, html, css, aframe, mute

I have a full screen 360 video but i want a mute button to be in the top right corner of the video. So far when loading at the start you can see the button but when the 360 video loads it does not appear, I assume it is above the video. How can I get it to appear? I am using a frame for the 360 video. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
     
    <!-- As if this Glitch were a typical HTML CodePen... -->    
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Use components defined in separate files. -->
    <script src="files/arrow-key-rotation.js"></script>
    <script src="files/play-on-window-click.js"></script>
    <script src="files/play-on-vrdisplayactivate-or-enter-vr.js"></script>
    <script src="files/hide-once-playing.js"></script>
    
    

    
<style>

</style>

<body>

    </body>

    <!-- Specify our scene. -->
    <a-scene>
     <div class="mutebg">   <button id="mutebtn">Unmute</button> </div>
      <a-assets>
    
        <img id="startImage" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ed9b722b-2185-451e-ac3b-efb27ab7e5bd/start-imagee2.jpg?v=1682461516019">
        <!-- Single source video  just like a normal HTML video element declaration -->
        <video  id="video"  
               autoplay loop crossorigin="anonymous" playsinline webkit-playsinline>
          <!-- MP4 video source. -->
          <source type="video/mp4"  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/2ffc75ed-46f3-4406-a68f-3a529ff49d1f/360_Trim.mp4?v=1682594245157"/>
        </video>
        
    
        
        <a-sky id="skyimage" src="#video"></a>
      </a-assets>
      
     
      <a-videosphere  src="#video" 
                     play-on-window-click
                     play-on-vrdisplayactivate-or-enter-vr>
      </a-videosphere>
      
      <!-- Define camera with zero user height, movement disabled and arrow key rotation added. -->
      <a-camera user-height="0" wasd-controls-enabled="false" arrow-key-rotation>
        <!-- Text element for display messaging.  Hide once video is playing. -->
        
      </a-camera>      
      
      <!-- Wait for the video to load. -->
      
       <!-- buttons. -->
    
        
      <a-plane  class="autumnsceneplane" position="-10 2 3" rotation=" 0 90 0" height="2" width="5" color="#68a4af" >     
        <a-text value="Cage size" scale="2 2 2" align="center" ></a-text>    
      </a-plane>
      </a>
      

      
       <a-plane   class="autumnsceneplane3" rotation="-90 0 0"  width="2" color="#68a4af"> 
       <a-text value="PlayPen" scale="1 1 1" align="center" ></a-text>   
         </a-plane>
         
         
         
    
         
         
         
         
              <a-plane  class="autumnsceneplane4" position="-2 1 -9"  height="2" width="5" color="#68a4af" >     
        <a-text value="Sleep" scale="2 2 2" align="center" ></a-text>    
      </a-plane>
      </a>
      
         
         
       
       
     
      
       <a-plane  id="autumnsceneplane" position="-8 -3 -10" rotation="0 45 0" height="2" width="5" color="#68a4af">     
        <a-text value="Click on Me " scale="2 2 2" align="center" ></a-text>    
      </a-plane>
      
      
      
      
       <a-plane  class="autumnsceneplane"  position="-8 -3 -10" rotation="0 45 0" height="2" width="5" color="#68a4af">     
        <a-text value="Click on Me " scale="2 2 2" align="center" ></a-text>    
      </a-plane>
      
       <a-plane class="autumnsceneplane2" position="10 0 -3" rotation="0 -90 0" height="2" width="5" color="#68a4af">     
        <a-text value="Sleep Schedule" scale="2 2 2" align="center" ></a-text>    
      </a-plane>
  <a-entity id="msg" geometry="primitive: plane; width:8; height:6" position="0 -0.3 -1.5" material="src:#startImage" 
                hide-once-playing="#video">
        </a-entity>
  <a-camera>
  <a-cursor></a-cursor>
  </a-camera>
 
    </a-scene>
    <script>
    
    
    var mutebtn;
intitializePlayer()  // **don't forget to call the initialize**

function intitializePlayer(){
    //set object references
    vid = document.getElementById("video");
    mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
    //add event listener
    mutebtn.addEventListener("click",vidmute,false);   // **quotes only around the event** 
}

function vidmute(){   // **there was an extra '.' between function and vidmute**
    if(vid.muted){
        vid.muted = false;
        mutebtn.innerHTML = "mute";
    } else {
        vid.muted = true;
        mutebtn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
    }
}
    
    
    
    
    document.querySelector('.autumnsceneplane').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    window.open("files/cagesize.html");
    })
    
    
        document.querySelector('.autumnsceneplane2').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    window.open("files/sleep.html");
    })
    
            document.querySelector('.autumnsceneplane3').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    window.open("files/playpen.html");
    })
    
                document.querySelector('.autumnsceneplane4').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    window.open("files/sleep.html");
    })
    

    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, your code contains some closing errors. But I'll give you a code to get this button task. Are you not using any css?

Comment: @DaniloFagundes Thanks for your reply. I'm going to use CSS to style the button but I was just going to get it to work first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
 .mute-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Replace your button with this one:

```
<div id="mutebtn" class="mute-button">the sound is on</div>
```

Remembering that your code has some errors and must be corrected, but this code will solve your sound button problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/u41mb8vp/

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! I'm still quite new to this what are closing errors? Thanks again

Comment: @volleyballdogsalad. Opens a new question, putting the complete code that managed to evolve. So I can put together a simulator of what you need to do. Success in your projects